# Why the files in NPM folder are not being included in Ionic ?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, npm

I just started learning Ionic and recently I have added `jquery` and `angular-ui-router` through `npm` which worked perfectly fine and created in `node_modules` folder. But when i start my app and tries to include those files they are not included. In console the error is `404 not found`. I have checked the path which is fine but its not working at all. May be its because the `node_modules` folder is outside the `www` folder. I am sharing an Image please tell me whats wrong.
[image: directory].

This is my `index.html`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"></meta>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"></link>
  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script> -->
  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <link href="asset_files/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <!-- your app's js -->
</head>

<body ng-app="starter">
  <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Cleaners</h1>
  </div>
  <ion-content class="has-header" ui-view>

  </ion-content>
  <div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced"></div>
  <script>

    document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='require.js'><\/script>");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my `require.js`.

```
    document.write("\
<script type='text/javascript' src='../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'><\/script>\
<script type='text/javascript' src='../node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js'><\/script>\
<script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'><\/script>\
<script type='text/javascript' src='asset_files/js/routes.js'><\/script>\
");
```

I am not being able to understand whats wrong. In console , network where the error is coming the path is this `http://localhost:8100/node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js`

Comment: can you be more clear please..i have not understood this line ` But when i start my app and tries to include those files they are not included`

Comment: Yes, I added the jquery and angular ui router min js file but they are not being included. the path is correct

Comment: add them in index.html and check

Comment: You need to copy the JS files in the www folder, you can create a custom script to do that for you automatically: https://luiscabrera.site/tech/2017/01/09/fontawesome-in-ionic2.html